# How can I fix the error-black box in elementary os?

Tags: release-loki

I'm new in Linux and I've installed Elementary os Loki. I've tried to install Dropbox, and later of that, a strange black box with a type forbidden symbol appeared (see image).

I've searched about that, but unfortunately I've not found anything, and I don't know what it means.  When I click on it, an empty tab is displayed.

I'll appreciate your help and thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easily fixed with a change to the autostart desktop file.
Edit `.config/autostart/dropbox.desktop` and change the Exec line to:

```
Exec=env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Unity QT_STYLE_OVERRIDE="" dropbox start -i
```

Log out and then back in and you should have a working icon in the systray.

The only problem is that dropbox likes to overwrite this file back to the original, so you may want to make it read-only and/or change the owner to prevent that.